# For each form option selected, add to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms, select

I have a multiple select form:

```
<form method="post" action="register_results.php" name="registerform" class="form-horizontal" role="form">

    <div class="label">Select Name:</div>
    <select name="names" multiple="yes" size="15">
    <option value = "">---Select---</option>
    <?php
    while ( $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo "<option value='".$row['registrant_name']."'>".$row['registrant_name']."</option>";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
    </select>  
</form>
```

The register_results.php file looks like this:

```
$registrant_name = $_POST['names'];
$event_result = $_POST['result'];


$query = "UPDATE events_regged SET result = $event_result WHERE event_name='event10' AND registrant_name=('$registrant_name') ";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

I want to be able to add multiple mysql rows (one row for each username) if multiple names are selected in the form. How can I do that?

Comment: If multi select is on, you will receive an array for $_POST['names'], and you can go from there.. EDIT:  thing to change is the name from **names** to **names[]**

Comment: @Naruto thanks but it's not really working for me.

Comment: Check ajaykumartak answer, and hopefully you will understand..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
<select name="names[]" multiple="yes" size="15">
```

instead of

```
<select name="names" multiple="yes" size="15">
```

and use foreach

```
foreach($_POST['names'] as $value)
{
//your query goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some changes required within your code as

```
<select name="names" multiple="yes" size="15">
              ^^^^^
```

it should be

```
<select name="names[]" multiple size="15">
```

This will result into an array so the result of

```
$registrant_name = $_POST['names']
```

will be an array

Comment: You want to store data comma separated or each selection has its own entry within database

Answer (score 0):

Change the form select element name from "names" to "names[]" and then you can access an array of posted values - which you can then iterate through.

Answer (score 0):

First change your form as below (it's more elegant and fast to use Id instead of  name (string) in Sql):

```
<select name="ids[]" multiple size="15">
    <option value = "">---Select---</option>
     <?php
       while ( $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo "<option value='".$row['registrant_id']."'>".$row['registrant_name']."</option>";
}
     mysqli_close($con);
?>
</select>
```

And in your PHP use foreach:

```
 $registrant_ids = $_POST['ids'];
 $event_result = $_POST['result'];
 foreach($registrant_ids as $id)
   {
     $query = "UPDATE events_regged SET result = $event_result WHERE event_name='event10' AND registrant_id=".$id;
     $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
   }
```